# Redisson client ; RedisTimeoutException issue

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, redis, redisson

I am using `Google cloud managed redis cluster(v5)` via `redisson(3.12.5)`

Following are my `SingleServer` configurations in yaml file

```
singleServerConfig:
    idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
    connectTimeout: 10000
    timeout: 3000
    retryAttempts: 3
    retryInterval: 1500
    password: null
    subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
    clientName: null
    address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
    subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
    subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
    connectionMinimumIdleSize: 40
    connectionPoolSize: 250
    database: 0
    dnsMonitoringInterval: 5000
threads: 0
nettyThreads: 0
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec> {}
```

I am getting following exceptions when I increase the load on my application

```
org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Unable to acquire connection! Increase connection pool size and/or retryInterval settings Node source: NodeSource 

org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command still hasn't been written into connection! Increase nettyThreads and/or retryInterval settings. Payload size in bytes: 34. Node source: NodeSource
```

It seems there is no issue on redis cluster and i think i need to make tweaking in my client side redis connection pooling confs(mentioned above) to make it work.

Please suggest me the changes i need to make in my confs

I am also curious if I should close the `Redis` connection after making get/set calls. I have tried finding this but found nothing conclusive on how to close `Redis` connections

One last thing that I want to ask is that is there any mechanism to get `Redis` connection pool stats(active connection, idle connection etc ) in `Redisson`

**Edit1:**

I have tried by changing values following values in 3 different iterations

**Iteration 1:**

```
 idleConnectionTimeout: 30000
 connectTimeout: 30000
 timeout: 30000
```

**Iteration 2:**

`nettyThreads: 0`

**Iteration 3:**

```
connectionMinimumIdleSize: 100
connectionPoolSize: 750
```

I have tried these things but nothing has worked for me

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing same issue, is there any solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting low memory alerts on your cache JVM.

You may have to analyze the traffic and determine 2 things

1. Too many parallel cache persists.
2. Huge chunk of data being persisted.

Both can be determined by the traffic on your server.

For option 1 configuring pool-size would solve you issue, but for option 2 you may have to refactor your code to persist data in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `nettyThreads = 64` settings